# Syncing a folder on computer with external drive

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, sync, external-hdd

I know that there are some file sync options (particularly rsync) available, but I'm trying to do something specific with my sync. I have a Movies folder with tons of video files, and I'd like to have an automatic sync where anything added to the Movies folder gets added to the corresponding videos folder on my external drive. I want to store all of my media in the external drive, and some of it on my computer. If I add something to the Movies folder on the computer, I would like for it to be added to the external drive automatically, however, I do not want to delete anything that is in the external but not in the internal drive. Basically, I would like for any new files in my computer to be added to the external drive automatically, but not have a true sync where things might get deleted from the external. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try luckyBackup from the software center.